# SUM(A1:A2) <> A1 + A2?

Tags: excel

I noticed that SUM(A1:A2) <> A1 + A2 returns true when A1 and A2 are boolean (e.g. A1=TRUE and A2=FALSE). The same applies to PRODUCT and the "*" operator. What is the rationale (if any) behind this strange behaviour?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I amended the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel stores True and False as logical values and when used in formulas, their numerical values are converted to 1 for True, and 0 for False. However, to have their values count in array formulas they must be entered manually instead of added by a reference, see below.

According to this [MSDN for SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb239771%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (emphasis added by me):

> • Numbers, **logical values**, and text representations of numbers **that you
> type directly into the list of arguments are counted**. See the first
> and second examples following.
>
> • **If an argument is an array or
> reference**, only numbers in that array or reference are counted. Empty
> cells, **logical values**, or text **in the array or reference are ignored**.
> See the third example following.

For instance, if you did `=SUM(TRUE,FALSE)` this would equal 1. But as you pointed out when you use the actual cell references the values are ignored.

Comment: Good answer, I wasn't aware that the array formulas would work like that.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. I can't see the reason of such a puzzling design (SUM(TRUE,FALSE)<>SUM(A1,A2) is amazing!).